# Regex does not match last optional group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to detect time in text. Everything works fine, except the last group wich is optional. If I would delete the `?`-sign, it works for that one example.

This is my regex: `^.*?(stell)?.*?(weck).*?(mich)?.*?((\d\d?).*?uhr(.*?(\d\d?))?|(\d\d?)\s*?(stunde|minute).*?((\d\d?)\s*?minute)?).*?$`

This are my examples:

```
weck mich um 2 uhr
wecke mich in 2 stunden
wecke mich um 15 uhr 13ojhwk
wecke mich in 5 minuten
stelle einen wecker für 5 minuten
stelle einen wecker in 5 stunden
stelle einen wecker für 12 stunden und 10 minuten lksdjglk
stelle einen wecker für 12 minute und 10 minuten lksdjglk
```

[image]

Here you can see, that regex isn't matching in the last two examples the group for `10 minute`. Is it possible to tell `?` that it should prefer the result if its there? (kind of weird explained)

Comment: It would greatly help if you describe what exactly you are trying to match.  Figuring that out from your regex is going to be difficult.

Comment: Try wrapping it with an optional non-capturing group: `(?:.*?((\d\d?)\s*?minute))?`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/y9Sp6D/1).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, the demo works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `.*?((\d\d?)\s*?minute)?` part with an optional non-capturing group, `(?:.*?((\d\d?)\s*?minute))?`:

```
^.*?(stell)?.*?(weck).*?(mich)?.*?((\d\d?).*?uhr(.*?(\d\d?))?|(\d\d?)\s*?(stunde|minute)(?:.*?((\d\d?)\s*?minute))?).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y9Sp6D/1).

The point is that the `((\d\d?)\s*?minute)` group becomes obligatory there, and the regex engine, due to the greedy `?` quantifier applied to that optional group, wants to match it right after `stunde` or `minute` (the previous obligatory group), so it cannot skip it.